# Didn't install Android emulator in beeware

Tags: python, windows, android-emulator, beeware

```
(venv) F:\beeware-virtual-development\first-project\helloworld>briefcase build android

[helloworld] Updating app metadata...
Setting main module... done

[helloworld] Building Android APK...
Downloading the Android emulator...
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Connection reset.
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to delete directory 'C:\Users\ale\AppData\Local\BeeWare\briefcase\Cache\tools\android_sdk\.temp\PackageOperation01' after 10 attempts
        at com.android.utils.PathUtils.deleteRecursivelyIfExists(PathUtils.java:129)
        at com.android.utils.PathUtils.lambda$addRemovePathHook$0(PathUtils.java:202)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: C:\Users\ale\AppData\Local\BeeWare\briefcase\Cache\tools\android_sdk\.temp\PackageOperation01
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:266)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
        at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
        at com.android.utils.PathUtils.deleteRecursivelyIfExists(PathUtils.java:88)
        ... 2 more
Building...

Error while installing Android emulator.

Log saved to F:\beeware-virtual-development\first-project\helloworld\logs\briefcase.2023_02_09-19_09_39.build.log
```

Comment: Do you get the same error every time you try this command?

Comment: yes about 5 time i try it

Comment: OK, StackOverflow isn't very good for debugging discussions, so please create an entry on the [Briefcase issue tracker](https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues), and include the log file mentioned in the message.

Comment: Anyway thanks bro i would like to test this way and if find answer shear in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello guys i found answer of my question just you should check virtulisation enable on your bios from your system and for check it you can see this future in your taskmanager cpu if is disable you should enable in from bios and if is enable it should work [image]

should be like this photo

see you later guys have nice time by by...